# How "document.getElementById" run together with "$(this).parent().trigger('submit')"?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Below are my codes, I have a form for user to fill up their information, when user click on the submit button,ow me how do I write the script correctly in order to call both event successfully?

```
<script>
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e){


});
</script>
```

Comment: The tiny section of code does not make a lot of sense in isolation, and your description of the issue is not clear. Could you please add all relevant code to the question (ideally in a working snippet) so that we can see the current behavior

Comment: It looks like you're... well.. submitting the form - this will force the page to reload (given no other evidence to stop it) so your next line will appear to have not worked (as the page has reloaded)

Comment: Hi all I added all relevant codes seeking for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing jQuery and plain js:

```
<script>
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e){

$(this).parent().parent().trigger('submit');
 $('#passvaluefunction').trigger('click'); 

});
</script>
```

Apart from that, you trigger a submit, so if you do not handle that by javascript or jQuery you leave the page before the click trigger.

Comment: *You are mixing jQuery and plain js* - so?  There's no conflict here.  They're not mixing js/jquery dom/objects.   (the other part is the same conclusion I came to)

Comment: Ok maybe i should have answered it the other way around.  Mixing both will work but can be very confusing, its better not to do that.

Comment: Hi all I added all relevant codes seeking for your help, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
<script>
$('.submitbutton').click(function(e){

 document.getElementById('passvaluefunction').click(); 
$(this).parent().parent().trigger('submit');


});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi all I added all relevant codes seeking for your help, appreciate it.